# What's the instruction for '&&' in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

I want to write an LLVM pass to reduce `&&` in LLVM IR, but I can't find the specific instructions for it in IR. For example,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    bool a = true;
    bool b = false;
    bool c = a && b;
    
    return 0;
}
```

and I get the IR,

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #4 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i8, align 1
  %3 = alloca i8, align 1
  %4 = alloca i8, align 1
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i8 1, i8* %2, align 1
  store i8 0, i8* %3, align 1
  %5 = load i8, i8* %2, align 1
  %6 = trunc i8 %5 to i1
  br i1 %6, label %7, label %10

7:                                                ; preds = %0
  %8 = load i8, i8* %3, align 1
  %9 = trunc i8 %8 to i1
  br label %10

10:                                               ; preds = %7, %0
  %11 = phi i1 [ false, %0 ], [ %9, %7 ]
  %12 = zext i1 %11 to i8
  store i8 %12, i8* %4, align 1
  ret i32 0
}
```

but I tried this one,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   int a = 10;
   int b = 10;
   int c;
   c = a && b;

   return 0; 
}
```

and I get this

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #4 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32 10, i32* %2, align 4
  store i32 10, i32* %3, align 4
  %5 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %6 = icmp ne i32 %5, 0
  br i1 %6, label %7, label %10

7:                                                ; preds = %0
  %8 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %9 = icmp ne i32 %8, 0
  br label %10

10:                                               ; preds = %7, %0
  %11 = phi i1 [ false, %0 ], [ %9, %7 ]
  %12 = zext i1 %11 to i32
  store i32 %12, i32* %4, align 4
  ret i32 0
}
```

I use LLVM 10 in ubuntu. I'll appreciate any answers or suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to write a pass to reduce && in LLVM IR"? What is a "pass"? What is the expected result if you "reduce &&"?

Comment: In a program which only has one line of observable code `return 0;`, why do you expect any other code to make it into the assembler or the binary? Modern compilers love to ignore anything without observable effect.

Comment: You have shown two pieces of assembler code, as if there is something strikingly weird about it. Assume that it is not and explain what puzzles you.

Comment: I wanna write a LLVM pass to implement instruction confusion for `&&`.  Using the examples is to show `&&` in different cases can convert to different instructions in IR. e.g. `trunc` `icmp`

Comment: Can somebody explain what a "pass" is? It seems that the meaning is so obvious that OP cannot answer that question.

Comment: This is a simple introduction about pass https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#introduction-what-is-a-pass

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in ways that invalidates or removes context from existing answers. It makes it hard to follow what's happening and you end up with answers that look like they're answering a question that wasn't asked and referencing code that isn't there (any more).

Comment: Sorry for that. I got it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no LLVM instruction that specifically corresponds to the `&&` operator. It can and will be translated in different ways depending on the expression and the optimization settings.

When you have optimizations enabled, the operands are side effect free (and not expensive to evaluate) and the whole expression can't be optimized away, `clang` will usually convert both operands to `i1` and apply the logical `and` operator on them.

When optimizations are disabled or the operands have side effects, it'll usually be translated using branch instructions. That's the case in the two examples you posted.

Note that `expr1 && expr2` is semantically equivalent to `expr1 ? expr2 : false` and you'll generally get the same LLVM code for both.

If you're okay with treating `expr1 ? expr2 : false` and other equivalent code (for example using `if` statements) the same as `&&`, you can try to detect the branching pattern created by them. If you need your pass to also be applicable after optimizations, you'll also have to detect at least the pattern of converting to i1 and `and`ing.

If you only want your transformation to apply to `&&` and nothing else, you simply can't do it at the LLVM level. You'd need an AST transformation at the Clang level.

Comment: Thanks. I want to achieve instruction confusion for &&, e.g. `bool c = a && b` converted to `bool c = (!(!a)) && b`. Using pass to achieve this, I think the first thing is to recognize the operator `&&`. If there isn't specifically responds to it, any suggestions?

Comment: @lcy There is no way to do that specifically for `&&` and only `&&` at the LLVM level. It would be straight forward to insert double negations for all `i1` values though. Do note that no-ops like this will disappear without a trace as soon as the optimizer gets its fingers on them.